# Blank value obtained when retrieving the text property for a control

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently working through a rather odd issue that I can't seem to figure out. I'm a novice programmer who is currently using VB.net to automate some lab equipment via the GPIB interface.

I'm using Excel to collect and tabulate my data. So the core of my problem is that I'm using a Backgroundworker to perform the "saving" of my data that I obtain from various lab equipment. Often times, I will have to record the assembly data of the specimens I'm testing. Here, I created another form with relevant fields to fill out all the data I'd ever desire to remember.

The backgroundworker thread will go into the secondary form, I've named it DAq6.vb, and pull the data. However, I've been noticing that it returns "" rather than the actual string that is present.

```
Public Function GetControlValue(ByVal ctl As Object) As String
    Dim text As String
    Try
        If ctl.InvokeRequired Then
            text = ctl.Invoke(New GetControlValueInvoker(AddressOf GetControlValue), ctl)
        Else
            If TypeName(ctl) = "ComboBox" Then
                text = ctl.Text
            ElseIf TypeName(ctl) = "NumericUpDown" Then
                text = ctl.value
            ElseIf TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Then
                text = ctl.Text
            ElseIf TypeName(ctl) = "RadioButton" Then
                text = ctl.Checked
            ElseIf TypeName(ctl) = "Decimal" Then
                text = ctl.Value
            ElseIf TypeName(ctl) = "Label" Then
                text = ctl.Text
            Else 
                text = "Type name unknown"
            End If
        End If
        Return text
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error: " & Err.Description)
    End Try
End Function
```

Above is the function that I use to safely retrieve a "control value" from a different thread.

And below is representative of the method I use to obtain values from the form I'm currently in (DAq1.vb). This code works, and it successfully retrieves the strings.

```
objRange = objSheet1.Range("B1")
objRange.Value = GetControlValue(txtDate)
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(objRange)
```

Here is code that doesn't work, curiously. I'm baffled as to why it wouldn't work.

```
objRange = objSheet6.Range("G2")
objRange.Value = GetControlValue(DAq6.txtLotNum1)
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(objRange)
```

Why would this be the case? Again, I'm a novice programmer that is primarily self-taught in VB.net syntax, so I apologize if this causes any cringing. But I have dug around the internet looking for an issue for a few days now, and I'm stumped.

Thank you so much for even just reading all of this!

Edit: I've adjusted the function according to Bjørn-Roger's suggestions. After inserting a breakpoint right before the error producing lines of code, I see that it correctly goes to the TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" portion of the if statement. Yet, it still returns a "" rather than the correct value.

Comment: Start by turning both [strict and explicit](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311329) `on`. Next add `Else : text = "Type name unknown"` after `ElseIf TypeName(ctl) = "Label" Then`.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Thanks for the suggestion! I should account for all the possibilities in the if statement. I turned strict and explicit on. I stepped through with a breakpoint placed right before the faulty code, and the function properly goes to `ElseIf TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox"`, but it still returns an empty string.

Comment: Can you show me where/how `DAq6` are instantiated?

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå By instantiated, do you mean a line such as `Dim D6 = New DAq6()` then rewriting `objRange.Value = GetControlValue(DAq6.txtLotNum1)` as `objRange.Value = GetControlValue(D6.txtLotNum1)`? I tried that as a suggestion from research I've done before, and it didn't seem to work. Otherwise, I don't call or instantiate `DAq6` anywhere within `DAq1` (the primary form).

Comment: Yes. If `DAq6` is a type rather than an instance of `DAq6` this will fail. You can use `My.Forms.DAq6` if the form has a parameterless constructor `Sub New()`. I'm pretty sure that the reason why it returns an empty string is because you're not referencing the correct instance. Try `Dim f = New DAq6() : f.txtLotNum1.Text = "test" :  objRange.Value = GetControlValue(f.txtLotNum1)` Assuming `txtLotNum1` is a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you return code on all paths and that you reference the correct instance of `DAq6`.

Here's a simple example:

```vb
Public Class DAq1
    'Inherits Form

    Public Sub New()
        Me.InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Public Function GetControlValue(ByVal ctl As Control) As String
        If (ctl Is Nothing) Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("ctl")
        End If
        Try
            If (ctl.InvokeRequired) Then
                Return CStr(ctl.Invoke(New GetControlValueInvoker(AddressOf GetControlValue), ctl))
            Else
                If (TypeOf ctl Is NumericUpDown) Then
                    Return DirectCast(ctl, NumericUpDown).Value.ToString()
                ElseIf (TypeOf ctl Is RadioButton) Then
                    Return DirectCast(ctl, RadioButton).Checked.ToString()
                Else
                    'Fallback to Control.Text
                    Return ctl.Text
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & Err.Description)
        End Try
        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Private Sub _DoWork(s As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles worker.DoWork
        Dim f As DAq6 = DirectCast(e.Argument, DAq6)
        e.Result = Me.GetControlValue(f.txtLotNum1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub _Completed(s As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles worker.RunWorkerCompleted
        If (e.Error Is Nothing) Then
            MessageBox.Show(CStr(e.Result), Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message, Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub _Shown(s As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        Dim f As New DAq6()
        f.txtLotNum1.Text = "YES!"
        Me.worker.RunWorkerAsync(f)
    End Sub

    Private WithEvents worker As New BackgroundWorker
    Public Delegate Function GetControlValueInvoker(ctl As Control) As String

    Public Class DAq6
        Inherits Form
        Public ReadOnly txtLotNum1 As New TextBox
    End Class

End Class
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your aid so far. I've tried adopting the techniques you demonstrated within your example, however I'm having difficulty. It has been made clear that I am very much a novice at this stuff, haha. I understand the changes you made to the `GetControlValue` function. But, I'm a bit confused. I desire to have the user set the value of `txtLotNum1`, but here you have it set to `"Yay!"`. Also, when I add the `Public Class DAq6` lines, when I press the button that calls for `DAq6` to show itself, it shows up as an empty default blank form.